# How do I submit multiple Spark jobs in parallel using Python and joblib?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, joblib

How do I submit multiple Spark jobs in parallel using Python's `joblib` library?

I also want to do a "save" or "collect" in every job so I need to reuse the same Spark Context between the jobs.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example to run multiple independent spark jobs in parallel without waiting for the first one to finish.

Other Approaches

- Don't use multiprocessing as it can't pickle spark context.
- Don't use Spark UDFs as spark jobs can't access the spark context

One caveat is that Spark FAIR scheduling must be set.

This solution uses threads instead of different processes so that

1. spark context can be shared between the different threads
2. local variables can be shared between the different threads

#### Code here to calculate the mean of means of some numbers

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, mean
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, LongType
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import pandas as pd
import random

lst = list(range(10, 100))

# Define functions operate on a single value from a column
def multiply(a):
  return a * random.randint(10, 100)

def foo(i):
  # This is the key point here, many different spark collect/save/show can be run here
  # This is the function that parallelizing can help to speed up multiple independent jobs
  return spark.createDataFrame(range(0, i), LongType()).select(mean(multiply(col("value"))).alias("value"))

parallel_job_count = 10
# Use "threads" to allow the same spark object to be reused between the jobs.
results = Parallel(n_jobs=parallel_job_count, prefer="threads")(delayed(foo)(i) for i in lst)

# Collect and print the results
mean_of_means = pd.concat([result.toPandas() for result in results]).value.mean()
print(f"Mean of Means: {mean_of_means}")
```

Comment: In order to use this code, how would you set FAIR scheduling?

Comment: Also, why does parallelizing runs require FAIR scheduling as opposed to FIFO scheduling?

Comment: The `prefer="threads"` was the key bit for me. Otherwise I was seeing the error: "It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast". Thank you!

Comment: @lightbox142 FAIR Scheduling is used to allow multiple spark jobs to run in parallel with the cluster balancing. FIFO would mean that the first job submitted would run to completion before the second would start, i.e. in sequence and not in parallel.

Comment: @lightbox142 Setting the FAIR scheduling is done by setting the spark config `spark.scheduler.mode` to FAIR